# How to specify CA certificate to grpc_cli

Tags: ssl, grpc

I'm working on a gRPC service, and we're using a CA certificate we generated ourselves for our server. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to tell grpc_cli about that certificate, and so I get "Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed."

I see an option for specifying the client cert and key, but not for the CA cert. What am I missing?

Comment: Which cli tool are you using?

Comment: @HelloWood - grpc_cli, the one that comes with the grpc packages.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Please post the answer if you have found by this time

Comment: @GaganTK - I was not able to find a way to do this so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
# tell gRPC where to look for a custom root of trust
% export GRPC_DEFAULT_SSL_ROOTS_FILE_PATH=path/to/ca.crt

# this now works :-)
% ./grpc_cli --ssl_target=localhost --channel_creds_type=ssl ls localhost:5255

see my problem to which this is the solution (v similar to yours) [here][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256356/why-am-i-getting-wrong-version-of-ssl-using-grpc-cli-with-a-service-compiled-aga/76273866#76273866
```