# why am I getting wrong version of SSL using grpc_cli with a service compiled against the grpc repo?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to use an SSL encrypted session with my grpc service, just using server authentication, not mutual (i.e. client too) authentication.

I've generated a self-signed cert using `openssl` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# generate the cert authority private key
openssl genrsa -passout pass:xxx -out ca.key 4096

# create the cert authority certificate
openssl req -passin pass:xxx -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj "/C=US/ST=TX/L=SanAntonio/O=MyCo/OU=Catena/CN=CatenaRoot"

# generate the server's private key
openssl genrsa -passout pass:xxx -out server.key 4096

# generate a signing request for the server
openssl req -passin pass:xxx -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=TX/L=SanAntonio/O=MyCo/OU=Catena/CN=localhost"

# create the server's cert
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:xxx -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

# remove password from server's key
openssl rsa -passin pass:xxx -in server.key -out server.key
```

And I'm using the certs in my service like this, which is adapted from one of the introductory examples at grpc.io.

```
ServerBuilder builder;
  std::string root_cert = readFile("$HOME/test_certs/ca.crt");
  std::string server_key = readFile("$HOME/test_certs/server.key");
  std::string server_cert = readFile("$HOME/test_certs/server.crt");
  grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions ssl_opts;
  ssl_opts.pem_root_certs = root_cert;
  ssl_opts.pem_key_cert_pairs.push_back(grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions::PemKeyCertPair{server_key, server_cert});
  // Listen on the given address without any authentication mechanism.
  builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::SslServerCredentials(ssl_opts));
  // Register "service" as the instance through which we'll communicate with
  // clients. In this case it corresponds to an *synchronous* service.
  builder.RegisterService(&service);
```

Running a basic `ls` command with `grpc_cli` results in these errors:

% ./grpc_cli ls localhost:5255
Received an error when querying services endpoint.
ServerReflectionInfo rpc failed. Error code: 14, message: failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNAVAILABLE: ipv4:127.0.0.1:5255: Socket closed, debug info: UNKNOWN:failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNAVAILABLE: ipv4:127.0.0.1:5255: Socket closed {file:"/Users//grpc/src/core/lib/transport/error_utils.cc", file_line:153, created_time:"2023-05-15T09:33:11.230046-05:00", grpc_status:14}

and I get these errors reported by the server:

```
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:5255
E0515 09:33:11.213626000 6170603520 ssl_transport_security.cc:1420]    Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
E0515 09:33:11.229645000 6168883200 ssl_transport_security.cc:1420]    Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
```

I've experimented a bit with the command line options for `grpc_cli` but could really use better documentation.

```
% ./grpc_cli --channel_creds_type ssl ls localhost:5255
E0515 11:50:13.329978000 8681347904 ssl_transport_security.cc:1420]    Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
E0515 11:50:13.348275000 8681347904 ssl_transport_security.cc:1420]    Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
Received an error when querying services endpoint.
```

The server side shows the same error messages as previously with `--channel_creds_type ssl` passed to `grpc_cli`

I've noticed that `grpc` doesn't use `openssl` by default; it builds against `boringssl-with-bazel`. I've tried to build it against openssl by passing `-DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package` in the initial call to `cmake` but that causes `grpc` to fail to build with link errors.

Thanks for reading this far. Any help greatly appreciated.

version info:

```
% openssl version
OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023)
```

I'm using the latest master branch of grpc.

Comment: example link error when trying to link against openssl instead of boringssl: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_ENGINE_by_id", referenced from:
      ssl_ctx_use_engine_private_key(ssl_ctx_st*, char const*, unsigned long) in libgrpc.a(ssl_transport_security.cc.o)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
# tell gRPC where to look for a custom root of trust
% export GRPC_DEFAULT_SSL_ROOTS_FILE_PATH=path/to/ca.crt

# this now works :-)
% ./grpc_cli --ssl_target=localhost --channel_creds_type=ssl ls localhost:5255
```

Comment: I eventually found what I needed here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/16059